# SOAP Spring WS - Jaxb2Marshaller does not include xsi:type when unmarshalling

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I'm working with a SOAP web service that seems to be fairly unforgiving with the format of the XML body it receives. For example, if I don't include the xsi:type property, like this:

```
<SOME_TAG>New York</SOME_TAG>
```

I get an error saying that "No Deserializer found to deserialize a 'SOME_TAG' using encoding style 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/'"

However, if I change the tag to this, all is fine:

```
<SOME_TAG xsi:type="xsd:string">New York</SOME_TAG>
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get the Jaxb2Marshaller to include the xsi:type attributes. I've tried adding 'type = String.class' in the @XmlElement annotation, but it didn't change the output.

Any tips or guidance are greatly appreciated!

Comment: That sounds very unusual for a SOAP WS. Is `SOME_TAG` defined to be a specific type in the `.wsdl` file? Is your program generating proper Namespace stuff?

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was unusual too. Here's what the definition looks like in the .wsdl file: <xsd:element name="SOME_TAG" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>. Namespace stuff looks normal to me.

Comment: Can you post the WSDL and the request XML? I think that would help in diagnosis.

Comment: Can you check if the WSDL says the binding type is `rpc/encoded`? You can check this under `binding style` and `body use` under the binding section in WSDL.

Comment: I'll see if I can cut up the file... it shouldn't be a problem, but I have limited access to the contents from my machine today (Sunday). In the meantime, the binding reads as: <soap:binding transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http' style='rpc'/>

Comment: That is the problem, if its RPC/encoded, then it will expect the types being defined in the request. Its not WS-I compliant. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-whichwsdl/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a pretty horrible answer, but I got it working by making sure that the data type in the WSDL file and the Java object class are different. So in in this case, I changed the Java annotation to be this:

```
@XmlElement(name = "SOME_TAG", type = java.lang.StringBuffer.class)
```

And when this gets marshaled, it ends up adding the xsi:type="xsd:string" attribute.

Like I said, not really a good answer - but it works.

Comment: Esto funciono para mi

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this with custom handler - you can intercept inbound/outbound message and customize it the way you want

```
public class AnnotationHandler  implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
...    
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) { 
    annotateSoapMessage(context, "handleMessage"); // write this **annotateSoapMessage** method
    return true;
}
```